# How do I add an application to Default Web Site in IIS 7?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have my main app at `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\`. I've created a separate application, and put it at `c:\inetpub\subapp`. I'd like to set it up so that if I visit http://www.mysite.com/subapp, it will run my subapp application.

I went into IIS, right-clicked on Default Web Site, and clicked Add Application. I set the physical path to my subapp, and tested it, but I got an error saying **"Invalid application path"**

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here, am I not adding the application correctly?

Comment: It is probably because the physical path does not exist. Check if it exists.

Comment: Don't worry about test settings. The application will still run anyways. I have a number of running applications where test settings gives me that message.

Answer (score 6):

Put it in `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\subapp\`.

In IIS Management Console, right click the Default Web Site node and choose Refresh.  You should see your site in a folder beneath there.

You can then right click on it and choose `Convert to Application`.

Comment: I tried that, but I still don't see my app in the IIS console. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Updated my answer ... have you refreshed the listings?

Answer (score 1):

Select "Connect as..." and select user that is part of "IIS_IUSRS" group.

Then "Test Settings..." again - that should work.